# Change Permission for Folders in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to give "Yes" to Read object for the Group "Everyone" under Public Access to all the folder contents of my S3 bucket. I am able to do this file by file. But I want to do it in bulk update without affecting other folders.

Is there any console kind of way where we run a command to implement the same? If yes how and what is the command to be used.

Editing the ACL of the bucket may affect all the contents in the bucket. I want to do it for specific folders.

Can anyone help me in this??

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. On findings, I came up to a conclusion as below.

1. Create a customized Bucket policy if you don't find them on Amazon predefined policies.
2. The policy can be as follows:

Refer Here:

```
{
"Version": "2000-11-15",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::Bucket_Name/Folder_Name/contents_1/contents_2/contents_3/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

3) For the resource part, I would recommend you to go to the Amazon Docs Link. [Click Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

Try this out, and let me know if you can do it. In case of any doubt loop it in this thread and will clear it off. All the best

Comment: What ever I want to do is in folder lever and not bucket level. I don't want to disturb the other content's in my bucket. Can you suggest any way other than changing the Bucket policy?

Comment: 1)  Goto Your Bucket ----> select a folder  ---->  go to the Permissions tab above and select the permission you wanted to provide.

2)  Go to your Bucket ---> select a folder  ----> go to overview and select the permission level

I think that would help ...

Comment: Got it !! Thanks a lot @Ashish